# Download internet pictures become low quality

Tags: gallery, images, wallpaper

I have downloaded a picture from internet:

[image]

But, when  I view it from gallery, it looks like very low quality. Its smoothness is completely gone:

[image]

I need to set a smooth picture as a wallpaper for my phone, and the downloaded version is too low quality to use. Can someone help me?

**Edit:** Looks like even my screenshot makes the web picture look blurry, anyway here is the link to the original picture:

http://picview.info/download/20150531/brown-shadow-background-black-1080x1920.jpg

Comment: please check the resolution and file size of downloaded image. It may be less than actual numbers, as it was downloaded from phone's browser.

Comment: @RahulGopi Can I download it in another way, like through a laptop then send to through bluetooth or something?

Comment: Yes. downloading from laptop/desktop have quality pictures. And you can share through bluetooth/USB. Also, keep in mind that its a `Full HD` image, which requires a `Full HD` screen for the best results.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's to do with the resolution of the wall paper you downloaded - it's 1080 * 1920 image , which is not high enough to be scaled properly on your device without blemishes as noticed by you

Typical Hi resolution wallpapers which give a better result are in the region of 1240 * 2208. You could Google those for the solid colours you are looking for or use an app like [Solid Colours](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=olga.moi.color) ( I haven't tried that app but use a different app that gives jet black wallpaper )

Comment: Solid colors is nice, but of course that picture has that smooth transition, not a single color. Thank you nevertheless.

Comment: True, you would need to Google for such high res images. App description claims to provide *textures and gradients* - maybe you could try that out